# CRUD RESTful tutorial

Tags: jersey, crud

I have successfully built a [CRUD RESTful webservice](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) according to this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html). However I am not having any luck whatsoever expanding on it. Specifically, I am trying to insert a new method somewhere (anywhere) that will accept the "ID" which is the parameter coming in from the web browser.

For example, I have tried every imaginable way I can think of to insert this method:

```
public class Gateway{

    public static void gateway (String id) throws IOException{
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter("C:\\Atest.txt");
            out.write("Hello "+id);
            out.close();
            }
}
```

Into either Class 5.3 [TodoResource](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) or [TodosResource](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).

For example in TodoResource:
Orginal-

```
// For the browser
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Todo getTodoHTML() {
    Todo todo = TodoDao.instance.getModel().get(id);
    if(todo==null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Get: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
    return todo;
}
```

My Attempt to pass gateway()-

```
// For the browser
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Todo getTodoHTML() {
    Todo todo = TodoDao.instance.getModel().get(id);
    if(todo==null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Get: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
Bridge.gateway(id)  //Here I tried to pass id   
return todo;
}
```

Can anyone give a heads up on how to incorporate my method into this example so that it doesnt ignore it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browser you are using, some browsers prefer APPLICATION_XML in favor of TEXT_XML. So it is likely that the following method is getting called instead of the one you are adding your Bridge.gateway(id) method to:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Todo getTodo() {
    Todo todo = TodoDao.instance.getModel().get(id);
    if(todo==null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Get: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
    return todo;
}
```